# How the UNIX file system forms a structure with nodes

Tags: unix, directory, filesystems, inode

I'm trying to understand how the UNIX file system works with regards to inodes. As I understand, a directory is represented as simply a table with an entry of the form [name:inode] for every subdirectory or file.

Where I am confused is how these directories form a structure. If i had a directory 'root' containing a subdirectory 'home' which contains a file 'file.txt' then i believe the root directory would have an entry ['home':(homes associated inode)] but then how does this link to the 'home' directory table?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct.  Here's a picture that might help.  I'm going to assume that the root directory is known to be inode 1.  So we might have:

inode 1:

```
type: directory
contents:
    usr       17
    etc       49
    home      57
```

inode 57:

```
type: directory
contents:
    dmr       201
    scs       857
    ben       981
```

inode 981:

```
type: directory
contents:
    .bashrc   1045
    projects  1191
    file.txt  2043
```

inode 2043:

```
type: file
contents:
    This is
    my text file.
```

Here I've shown the situation that the full path (or at least, a full path) of your text file is `/home/ben/file.txt`.

(I've also made one big simplification.  Typically, a file's contents are *not* stored in the inode, but rather, in other disk blocks, with the inode containing pointers to those other blocks.)

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful! You mention that the contents are stored via pointers to disk blocks, are the inode numbers also pointers to other inode locations on disk or are they managed some other way?

Comment: @BenJacob This I'm less sure of, and I think different filesystem implementations do it in different ways.  I think there's usually a structured mapping between inodes and disk blocks. For example, disk block 100 might contain inodes 10-19, disk block 200 might contain inodes 20-29, etc.  Directory entries in directory inodes map to inode numbers, disk block pointers in inodes point to disk block numbers.  To convert an inode number `i` to a disk block, take `(i/10)*100` and then look at the `(i%10)`'th inode in that block.  Or something like that.

Comment: I see so in this configuration am I right in assuming that the number of inodes and blocks are fixed and when we create a directory we simply fill an empty inode with the new information?

Comment: @BenJacob Yes, the number of available blocks and inodes is usually fixed, with the ratio set when the filesystem is created.  On most systems, the `df` command shows total, used, and percent-used numbers for both blocks and inodes.

Comment: This is a very good description.  (Bear in mind, that it makes many simplifications.)  My only critique is one detail that I think is too often simplified, and leads to some confusion, and may be appropriate to point out even (especiall) at this level of introduction.  Namely, `/home/ben/file.txt` is one possible path of the file.  If `/home/ben/tmp/file.txt` also links to that same inode, then there is *no* difference between the two paths.  I would suggest writing 'I've shown the situation where `/home/ben/file.txt` is a path to your file."

Comment: @WilliamPursell You're right, although this is the sort of nuance that can be too distracting in a simplified first presentation.  I've inserted a parenthetical, and then your comment here serves as a useful footnote.